# Consumir API REST JSON con PHP

Tags: php, jsonobject, jsonarray

Buen dia comunidad, tengo una consulta en la que ojala me puedan orientar un poco. Estoy implementando una api que me proporciono un cliente que devuelve la siguiente informacion al consultarse por el enlace que me proporciono.

```
{
"INFO_LOTE": {
"PRECIO": "0 MXN",
"LOTE": "510",
"M2_LOTE": "65.45",
},
"PLANES": {
"HIPOTECARIO": {
"DESCUENTO PLAN": "0 MXN",
"AHORRO": "0",
"ENGANCHE_PRCENTAJE": 10,
"ENGANCHE": "0 MXN",
"DURANTE_OBRA_PORCENTAJE": 20,
"DURANTE_OBRA": "0 MXN",
"MENSUALIDADES": "35",
"MENSUALIDAD": "0 MXN",
"A_LA_ENTRGA_PORCENTAJE": 50,
"A_LA_ENTRGA": "0 MXN"
},
"FINANCIERO 1": {
"DESCUENTO PLAN": "0 MXN",
"AHORRO": "0",
"ENGANCHE_PRCENTAJE": 20,
"ENGANCHE": "0 MXN",
"DURANTE_OBRA_PORCENTAJE": 30,
"DURANTE_OBRA": "0 MXN",
"MENSUALIDADES": "35",
"MENSUALIDAD": "0 MXN",
"A_LA_ENTRGA_PORCENTAJE": 100,
"A_LA_ENTRGA": "0 MXN"
},
"N/D": {
"DESCUENTO PLAN": "0 MXN",
"AHORRO": "0",
"ENGANCHE_PRCENTAJE": 0,
"ENGANCHE": "0 MXN",
"DURANTE_OBRA_PORCENTAJE": 0,
"DURANTE_OBRA": "0 MXN",
"MENSUALIDADES": "0",
"MENSUALIDAD": "0 MXN",
"A_LA_ENTRGA_PORCENTAJE": 100,
"A_LA_ENTRGA": "0 MXN"
},
"FINANCIAMIENTO 2": {
"DESCUENTO PLAN": "0 MXN",
"AHORRO": "0",
"ENGANCHE_PRCENTAJE": 20,
"ENGANCHE": "0 MXN",
"DURANTE_OBRA_PORCENTAJE": 60,
"DURANTE_OBRA": "0 MXN",
"MENSUALIDADES": "35",
"MENSUALIDAD": "0 MXN",
"A_LA_ENTRGA_PORCENTAJE": 20,
"A_LA_ENTRGA": "0 MXN"
},
"CONTADO": {
"DESCUENTO PLAN": "0 MXN",
"AHORRO": "0",
"ENGANCHE_PRCENTAJE": 70,
"ENGANCHE": "0 MXN",
"DURANTE_OBRA_PORCENTAJE": 0,
"DURANTE_OBRA": "0 MXN",
"MENSUALIDADES": "0",
"MENSUALIDAD": "0 MXN",
"A_LA_ENTRGA_PORCENTAJE": 30,
"A_LA_ENTRGA": "0 MXN"
}
}
}
```

Intente llamar la informacion con el siguiente codigo pero solo me muestra todo el contenido del array INFO_LOTE. Mi duda es, como mostrar los planes que muestra el api.

```
<?php
$urlinfo = "htttps://url...";
$data3 = json_decode(file_get_contents($urlinfo),true);
$var = $data3['INFO_LOTE'];
echo $var["PRECIO"]."<br>";
echo $var["LOTE"]."<br>";
echo $var["M2_LOTE"];
?>
```

Ya investigue bastante pero no logro dar con una respuesta que muestre algo similar a lo que estoy usando, por eso es que recurro a ustedes en busca de ayuda, ojala me puedan orientar un poco mas, saludos a todos.

Comment: `var_dump($data3['PLANES'])`

Comment: planes es un array `print_r($data3["PLANES"]);`

Comment: Gracias John, gracias ffflabs, me funciono perfecto. Solo que lo que estoy buscando es mostrar cada valor independiente como en INFO_LOTE.

Comment: Aquí el problema que tienes es que esa API te devuelve un objeto con unas claves que "creo" son los planes. Te va a tocar ir por cada clave de plan. Puedes acceder con $data3["PLANES"]["HIPOTECARIO"], $data3["PLANES"]["FINANCIERO 1"], $data3["PLANES"]["N/D"], $data3["PLANES"]["FINANCIAMENTO 2"] 
y $data3["PLANES"]["CONTADO"]. Lo suyo sería que dentro de planes tuvieras un array para recorrerlo, pero por lo que veo no es tu caso. Yo hablaría con el cliente para que viera el problema y que lo cambiara.

Comment: Jakala, muchas gracias por responder. Me has salvado aunque si, en efecto note ciertas incongruencias en el json que devolvía pero con tu ayuda pude resolverlo para presentar la propuesta al cliente. Te agradezco bastante.